# How to Mid data in Online Google Excel?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Ok, given this string `21h*Available*SB*Ha` in Cell A2 in Google Excel, how to form formula so that we can get individual data (* is the delimiter)

```
A2                   - B2  - C2        - D2 - E2

21h*Available*SB*Ha  - 21h - Available - SB - Ha
```

Ok, I can do the "B2" by using this formula "=mid(A2,1,3)"

But I don't know how to use formula for other cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way, in Excel:

```
B2:  =TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"*",REPT(" ",99)),MAX((COLUMNS($A:A)-1)*99,1),99))
```

and fill right as far as needed.

The formula replaces the delimiter with a large number of spaces -- some number that is greater than the longest substring; and then we use a formula that successively generates the values for the start of the mid function.  In the above, it would be {1,99,198,297}; take 99 characters and trim the results.

If you do not require a formula, you could use the Text-to-Columns tool.

Answer (score 2):

Just use split :

```
=split(A1,"*")
```

Comment: I was not aware of that function.  Apparently present in Google Sheets, but not in Excel.

Comment: sometimes, the text is like this "122***12" then it should create empty column for "****" but split function didn't do that

Comment: Can you modify the formula so that it take empty columns, example =split("1***2","*") should create 2 empty columns between "1" & "2"?

Answer (score 0):

Formula to split *** and make extra spaces:

`=ArrayFormula(TRIM(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"\*","* "),"*")))`

> example =split("1***2","*") should create 2 empty columns between "1"
>   & "2"